# remove view from navigator controller

Tags: ios

I have

```
NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

On my newViewController, there's a cancel button. When I click on this cancel button I want to go back to my previous navController. How do I do this?

I tried [self view] removeFromSuperView but that just made the screen white but doesnt go back to the previous navController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pushed the view controller, what you want to do now is pop it off the view controllers stack. This way:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```